Looking for references for easy facts about Zeckendorf and dual Zeckendorf representations
I'm looking to find references to cite for some easy facts about Zeckendorf representations and dual Zeckendorf (aka lazy Fibonacci) representations.  Most of these are definitely known because e.g. I've seen them stated on OEIS or Wikipedia (and a few are I'd say well-known), and they're not hard to show, but I'd still like to know what to cite for them.  Specifically:

For $n>0$, the number of trailing zeroes in the Zeckendorf representation of $n$ is even iff the dual Zeckendorf representation of $n$ ends in a $1$.
The number of trailing ones in the dual Zeckendor representation of $n$ is even iff the Zeckendorf representation of $n$ ends in a $0$.
If we perform a left shift on (append a $0$ to) the Zeckendorf representation of $n$, we get $\lfloor(n+1)\varphi\rfloor-1$.
If we perform a right shift on (delete the last digit of) the dual Zeckendorf representation of $n$, we get $\lfloor\frac{n}{\varphi}\rfloor$.
If we we do this for ordinary Zeckendorf instead, then we get $\lfloor\frac{n+2}{\varphi}\rfloor-1$.
Finally, this one I haven't seen stated anywhere, but a really nice fact I'd like a citation for (it has to be known, right?) is that if you consider "improper Zeckendorf representations", i.e. Zeckendorf representations without consecutivity restrictions, then left-shift is well-defined; that is, given two improper Zeckendorf representations for the same number, then after appending a $0$ they still represent the same number.  (In particular, appending a $0$ to ordinary Zeckendorf and to dual Zeckendorf yield the same number.)

(Proof sketch for that last one: It suffices to consider the case where one representation is actual Zeckendorf, so consider the algorithm for converting an improper Zeckendorf representation to actual Zeckendorf, and observe that every step of it commutes with left shift.)
So, anyone know what I could cite for these?  Thanks all!
